# Unable to run mapreduce wordcount

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to teach myself some hadoop basics and so have build a simple hadoop cluster. This works and I can put, ls, cat from the hdfs filesystem without any issues.
So I took the next step and tried to do a wordcount on a file I had put into hadoop, but I get the following error

```
 $ hadoop jar /home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*examples*.jar wordcount     data/sectors.txt results
2018-06-06 07:57:36,936 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager     at ansdb1/10.49.17.12:8040
2018-06-06 07:57:37,404 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1528191458385_0014
2018-06-06 07:57:37,734 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2018-06-06 07:57:37,869 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2018-06-06 07:57:37,923 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2018-06-06 07:57:38,046 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1528191458385_0014
2018-06-06 07:57:38,048 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2018-06-06 07:57:38,284 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2018-06-06 07:57:38,284 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2018-06-06 07:57:38,382 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1528191458385_0014
2018-06-06 07:57:38,445 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ansdb1:8088/proxy/application_1528191458385_0014/
2018-06-06 07:57:38,446 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1528191458385_0014
2018-06-06 07:57:45,499 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1528191458385_0014 running in uber mode : false
2018-06-06 07:57:45,501 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2018-06-06 07:57:45,521 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1528191458385_0014 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1528191458385_0014 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1528191458385_0014_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-06-06 07:57:43.301]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1528191458385_0014_02_000001
Exit code: 1

[2018-06-06 07:57:43.304]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster

Please check whether your etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml contains the below configuration:
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>

[2018-06-06 07:57:43.304]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster

Please check whether your etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml contains the below configuration:
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${full path of your hadoop distribution directory}</value>
</property>

For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://ansdb1:8088/cluster/app/application_1528191458385_0014 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
2018-06-06 07:57:45,558 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

I have searched lots of website and they seem to say that my environment isn't right. I have tried many of the suggested fixes, but nothing has worked.

Everything is running on both nodes:

```
$ jps
31858 ResourceManager
31544 SecondaryNameNode
6152 Jps
31275 DataNode
31132 NameNode
$ ssh ansdb2 jps
16615 NodeManager
21290 Jps
16478 DataNode
```

I can ls hadoop:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /
Found 3 items
drwxrwxrwt   - hadoop supergroup          0 2018-06-06 07:58 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2018-06-05 11:46 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2018-06-05 07:50 /usr
```

hadoop version:

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 3.1.0
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop -r 16b70619a24cdcf5d3b0fcf4b58ca77238ccbe6d
Compiled by centos on 2018-03-30T00:00Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 14182d20c972b3e2105580a1ad6990
This command was run using /home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.0.jar
```

hadoop classpath:

```
$ hadoop classpath
/home/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*
```

my environment is setup:

```
# hadoop
## JAVA env variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

## HADOOP env variables
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

My hadoop xml files

core-site.xml:

```
$ cat $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://ansdb1:9000/</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
$ cat $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/data/hadoop/datanode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>/data/hadoop/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.checkpoint.dir</name>
  <value>/data/hadoop/secondarynamenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
$ cat $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>ansdb1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
  <value>ansdb1:8025</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
  <value>ansdb1:8030</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
  <value>ansdb1:8040</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
$ cat $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

I have checked which jar file contains MRAppMaster:

```
$ find /home/hadoop -name '*.jar' -exec grep -Hls MRAppMaster {} \;
/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-3.1.0-sources.jar
/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-3.1.0-test-sources.jar
/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-3.1.0.jar
```

Clearly I am missing something, so could somebody please point me the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

After much googling of the same question asked different ways, I found this https://mathsigit.github.io/blog_page/2017/11/16/hole-of-submitting-mr-of-hadoop300RC0/ (it's in Chinese).
So I set the following properties in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
 <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
 <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
 <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
```

And everything works

Comment: Just came across this now.  I'm glad you solved it, but notice that the output you received and cut & pasted above actually has this exact answer.